# space indentation expected - Codacy

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, codacy

I heard that good practice is to use something to check my code. I found something called [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/). I understand everything except 'space indentation expected' from TSLint and TSLint4. Is it because my ident in project is tab? If yes, how can I change this one rule in codacy?

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule}  from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {TranslationModule} from '../translate.module';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'admin',
        children: [
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(adminRoutes), TranslationModule
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    exports: [
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Codacy show problem with

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    children: [
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/). for instance:

```
"indent": [true, "tabs", 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

see also :
maintain consistent styling with angular style guide using tslint

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/lint

```
"indent": [true, "tabs", 4]
```